# GoogleTest several C++ projects in the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I have e.g. 10 C++ projects in a solution `SolA` and want to UnitTest them with GoogleTest:

so I created a new solution `SolATest` and for every project of `SolA` an unit test project in `SolATest`!

Is it a good approach to load the SolA libraries implicit in SolATest/Projects and run every test project as an executable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv); 
    int value = RUN_ALL_TESTS();

    std::getchar(); // to hold the terminal open

    return value;
}
```

or is there a more convenience way -> e.g. only have one executable in `SolATest` and load the other test projects as libraries (IMHO to have all cpp files in one test project is confusing)?!

Thx for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either approach should work; it just depends on your preference. I tend to follow a project structure like the following:

```
Solution
 |-- ProjectA 
 |-- ProjectATests
 |-- ProjectB
 |-- ProjectBTests
 `-- TestLib
```

Where the projects (ProjectA, ProjectB) are libraries, and each test project (ProjectATests, ProjectBTests) is an executable. Note that we do *not* separate unit tests into a separate solution; they are always built and run alongside the production code. I like this structure for a few reasons:

1. It's easier to run just the tests that are related to your changes.
2. The development workflow is a bit more efficient, since when making changes to one library you only have to rebuild and link the corresponding test.

Whether you create a single test project or multiple, I would definitely recommend putting the project in the same solution as the code under test. Further, I would recommend setting up a post-build step for the test project(s) which runs the tests and fails the build if they don't pass.

Lastly, you might be wondering about that 'TestLib' project. I use that for the gtest/gmock fused sources, the definition of main(), and any other utilities that are shared between tests. That eliminates (or at least, reduces) code duplication between the various test projects.